# Move marker in android map

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to move a marker in map view. At first, I do like this:

```
public void moveMarker(Marker marker, int lng, int lat) {       
    if (marker == null) {
        return;
    }
    String key = marker.getKey();
    OverlayItem item = (OverlayItem) markers.get(key);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    GeoPoint oldPoint = item.getPoint();
    if (oldPoint.getLatitudeE6() == point.getLatitudeE6()
            && oldPoint.getLongitudeE6() == point.getLongitudeE6()) {
        return;
    }
    overlay.removeOverlay(item);
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(point, marker.getTitle(), marker
            .getSnippet());
    newItem.setMarker(marker.getIcon());
    overlay.addOverlay(newItem);
    mapView.postInvalidate();
    markers.put(key, newItem);

}
```

Yes, this works. But when a marker moves, the other markers refresh. So I modify code like the followings:

```
public void moveMarker(Marker marker, int lng, int lat) {
    if (marker == null) {
        return;
    }
    String key = marker.getKey();
    MarkerOverlay overlay = markers.get(key);
    OverlayItem item = overlay.getItem(0);
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);
    GeoPoint oldPoint = item.getPoint();
    if (oldPoint.getLatitudeE6() == point.getLatitudeE6()
            && oldPoint.getLongitudeE6() == point.getLongitudeE6()) {
        return;
    }
    mapOverlays.remove(overlay);
    MarkerOverlay overlayN = null;
    if (marker instanceof CarMarker) {
        CarMarker cm = (CarMarker) marker;
        overlayN = new CarMarkerOverlay(null, mapView, cm.getCarId());
    } else if (marker instanceof Marker) {
        overlayN = new MarkerOverlay(null);
    }
    OverlayItem newItem = new OverlayItem(point, marker.getTitle(),
            marker.getSnippet());
    newItem.setMarker(marker.getIcon());
    overlayN.addOverlay(newItem);
    mapOverlays.add(overlayN);
    markers.put(key, overlayN);
    mapView.postInvalidate();
}
```

This works as I wanted. But there is a question, every time marker moves, it will remove MarkerOverlay and recreate it, is it inefficient? Thanks in advance!
the variables named markers and mapOverlays definition:

```
private Map<String, MarkerOverlay> markers = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MarkerOverlay>();
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays = null;
mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
```

Some class definition:

```
public class MarkerOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>{}
public class CarMarkerOverlay extends MarkerOverlay {}
```